# jQuery variable made of a variable and selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to construct a variable like the following:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'Breakfast',
    clientId: 'bff2c0f300c841a298a9198e499eee16',
    limit: 50,
    target:'instagramFeedBottom',
    template: '<li class="panel"><a href="{{link}}"><img class="front card" src="{{image}}" /></a><a href="{{link}}"><div class="back card"><p>{{model.user.full_name}}</p></div></a></li>',
    after: function() {
        RandomImg();
    },
    resolution: 'low_resolution'
});


    $('.front').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            var x = $(this).parent().parent();
            console.log(x + $('.back'));
        }
        // mouseleave: function () {
        //    $(this).fadeIn(medium);
        // }
    });
```

I am having the following error in the console: [object Object][object Object]. I need to access the '.back' based on the '.front'.parent().parent()

Comment: `console.log(x.find('.back'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `x` is a jQuery object use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like

```
console.log(x.find('.back'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need The context selector

```
$('.back', x)
```

*OR*

You can also use

```
x.find('.back')
```

Note: jQuery internally converts `$('.back', x)` to `x.find('.back')`

Comment: Why x is after as x suppose to be .panel?

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for that , although I was looking for an explanation to the fact my (wrong) solution didnt work console.log(x + $('.back'));.